# Building a boat - out of recyclables

Tags: recycling, diy, construction, boat

Looking for ideas to make a boat out of mostly recycled material. Two idea's that come to mind is cardboard and use weather sealer on it, and caulking the edges or plastic bottles, jugs, and the like tied together and fasten a board over the top.

I have already made a cardboard boat that was able to carry more than a thousand pounds of people, at the time we had seven people on board. I would really like to make another one. Mostly looking for ways to improve or get fresh ideas.

Uses: Fishing, Ease of travel, and\or cargo transportation.

Bonus points for durability and reusability.

Comment: Welcome to Sustainability! I admire your efforts, but I think as it is your question is rather broad and open-ended which makes it a poor fit for this website. We prefer questions that can be answered objectively. More info about this in our [Help Center](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/asking). Perhaps you can point out the weak points of your current design, so people can focus their answers on better solutions for that?

Comment: Related question: [How to make a fully reused/reusable plastic bottle raft?](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/734/99)

Comment: I don't know, but since a proper boat properly maintained is going to last for such a long time my feeling is that buying a proper boat either from sustainably sourced wood / recycled aluminium or second-hand might be the more sustainable choice.